# $_POST['index'] value echoes string but getting undefined error with readfile function

Tags: php, jquery, post, force-download

Here is the jQuery code I am using to send a random_num to force_dl.php, where random_num has the value 977926... my end goal is to force data977926.data to be downloaded instead of opened in a new window.

```
$.post( "../scripts/force_dl.php",{
    random_num: random_num
},
function( data ) {
    alert( data );
    var data_file = document.getElementById("data_file");
    data_file.href = "../scripts/force_dl.php";
});
```

and here is the HTML code being modified

```
<a id="data_file">Download data file</a>
```

When I have the following in force_dl.php,

```
<?php $file_name = "data" . $_POST['random_num'] . ".data";
echo "$file_name"; ?>
```

I see the file name in an alert,

```
data977926.data
```

and if I run the following in force_dl.php

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=data257667.data");
header("Content-type: text/plain");
readfile("../queries/gnuplot_tmp_files/data257667.data");
```

and click the HTML link with ID data_file, I am forced to download the data text file, as desired.
    The problem comes when I run the following. When I click the same data_file link I download a file named data.data!

```
$file_name = "data" . $_POST['random_num'] . ".data";
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Content-type: text/plain");
readfile("../queries/gnuplot_tmp_files/$file_name");
```

Here is what is inside the data.data file,

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: random_num in     <b>/var/www/html/msdb/scripts/force_dl.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(../queries/gnuplot_tmp_files/data.data): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in     <b>/var/www/html/msdb/scripts/force_dl.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

Why is the index random_num undefined when I can echo $_POST['random_num'] just fine? Why is the downloaded file named data.data instead of data977926.data? Why do I see data977926.data when I echo $_POST['random_num'] but am getting different results than when I insert $_POST['random_num'] into the header and readfile functions than when I enter data977926.data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data_file.href = "../scripts/force_dl.php";` There are no parameters so that's why you get `Undefined index`

Comment: And besides, clicking a link makes the browser do a GET request, not a POST request. You have two completely different requests here – the first POST request that you make via `$.post`, and that transfers the POST parameter, and the second one, triggered by the clicking the link, which is a GET request – and those two have nothing whatsoever to do with each other.

Comment: You are not recognizing that it is 2 separate requests and the php script will run each time

Comment: instead of doing an ajax followed by a javascript redirect (which makes no sense in this context) do a form submission via javascript `form.submit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JavaScript change

```
data_file.href = "../scripts/force_dl.php";
```

To this:

```
data_file.href = "../scripts/force_dl.php?random_num=" + random_num;
```

And in the php file for downloading change

```
$file_name = "data" . $_POST['random_num'] . ".data";
```

To this:

```
$file_name = "data" . $_GET['random_num'] . ".data";
```

This way you will pass the random number via GET method in the link to the php file, in your current code you aren't telling the php file in the second time what to get.

Please note that if you want to use same php file for both of these actions you can check input values at first via isset function and do the right action based on them like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['random_num'])){
    echo 'data'.$_POST['random_num'].'.data';
}elseif(isset($_GET['random_num'])){
    $file_name = 'data'.$_GET['random_num'].'.data';
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    readfile('../queries/gnuplot_tmp_files/'.$file_name);   
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. As other users pointed out I wasn't realizing that there were two requests going on - one post and one get. Your solution worked and helped clarify that.

Comment: By the way, don't forget to to check the validity of inputs in php, now anyone can send any kind of requests with their custom values for `$_POST['random_num']` and `$_GET['random_num']` and probably download a file that you don't want them to get it.